# Does VirtualBox support line in and the microphone?

Tags: windows-7, audio, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am running windows 7 on my host which has the microphone working just fine but I cannot get the mic to work under any guest (I have tried Ubuntu 10.4 and Windows XP). I am beginning to think that VirtualBox does not support the microphone.

Answer (score 7):

According to this [VirtualBox ticket](http://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4302), this problem was fixed under version 3.1.4 of VirtualBox. Are you using 3.1.4 or later?

Comment: According to this [VirtualBox ticket] (https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/8573) it is again not fixed.

Answer (score 2):

This could be because of some problem with alsa configuration. Try checking out the current alsa configuration.
`alsactl store -f /tmp/foo`

open /tmp/foo and check the values for `Mux capture volume`. If there is no entry for `Mux capture volume`, vbox is not able to virtualize the mic device. Turn off the vm image and in the settings-->audio section, try changing the `Audio controller` to some other device, if any.

start the vm again and store the config again
`alsactl store -f /tmp/bar`

open and look for `Mux capture volume`, if its there, modify the `value.0` and `value.1` to some higher value (but within the range of DbMin and DbMax). save the file and restore the config using:
`alsactl restore -f /tmp/bar`

This should work for you.

If there is no option for 'Mux capture volume`, I think that u won't be able to record using microphone from ur vm :(